# Converting a .nmf file into .wav format executes the code showing Restart: with no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, wav, sys

I have found code on github that's supposed to take a .nmf file and convert the audio into a .wav file. The code is availlable here:

https://github.com/quarckster/nmf_to_wav/blob/master/nmf_converter.py

When I run this code in IDLE adding the path_to_file's to be the directory where my .wav file is saved to the code, I get an output of
    RESTART: and nothing else. I was expecting to get a file that is converted to .wav format. What went wrong? How can I fix it?

Thank you

Comment: The `RESTART` is what IDLE normally says when you run a program and it indicates that any previous values lying around have been thrown away.. The code you refer to doesn't have any `print()` calls, so it appears that in the normal case you shouldn't actually expect IDLE to display any output. Are you confident that the file wasn't created?

Comment: @BoarGules, thank you for the prompt response. What do you mean by file not created? Well, where would it save to? I don't see it in that directory

Comment: According to the code, given the input file `mysound.nmf` it should produce one or more numbered files in the same folder called `mysound_stream0.wav` (etc). All that the module does is use `subprocess` to run the program `ffmpeg`. I would try running that program by hand first. The likeliest possibility is that you don't have that program, or you do but it is not on your path.

Comment: @BoarGules, sorry, not sure if I fully follow you. Where are you finding mysound_stream? I don't see this in the code. How would I run the program manually?

Comment: The name of the new output file is computed in this line: `output_file = os.path.splitext(path_to_file)[0] + "_stream{}".format(stream_id) + ".wav"`. `mysound` isn't in the code. I used that as an example of what your input filename might be. You didn't say what it actually was. You run the program manually by opening a terminal/Windows console window and typing `ffmpeg` and seeing what happens.

Comment: when I type ffmpeg in the terminal it says 'ffmpeg' is not a recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Then, as I said, you either don't have that program or it isn't on your path. The Python program you are running is expecting to be able to find it.

Comment: so does that mean I need to pip install it?

Comment: No, because it isn't a Python program, it's an `.exe`.

Comment: so what do you recommend that I do?

Comment: I tried *download ffmpeg* in Google and the first hit I got was https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html so that looks like a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, so I just downloaded the ffmpeg folder and saved it to the same directory where my .py and .wav files are located, reran the code, and the output coming out is exactly the same as before

Comment: Putting the `ffmpeg` program in the same folder won't necessarily enable the Python program to find it. *It must be on the path.* Read the docs for `ffmpeg`, find out how to run the program by hand, and you will probably discover you don't really need that Python program anyway. The documentation seems to be very complete.

Comment: Pretty sure I need this in Python because the person who gave me the assignment told me with the current code, they seem to get part of the audio cut off in the conversion process, I am supposed to figure out how to get the full thing to work.

Comment: All the Python program does is call `ffmpeg` to do the heavy lifting. It does *absolutely no conversion itself*. So running `ffmpeg` from the command line doesn't work as expected, then the Python program is *absolutely not* going to fix it, because the Python program doesn't do any more than you could do by typing the command line in yourself. If `ffmpeg` cuts off the audio then the problem is most likely in the input. As I said over an hour ago, run `ffmpeg` by hand first and get it to do what you want. I can't say it any clearer, sorry.